# Case expressions must be constant expressions for static final int?

Tags: java, switch-statement, final

I have a `final class Ring` defined as:

```
final class Ring {
    public static final int OUT = 3;
    public static final int MID = 2;
    public static final int IN  = 1;
}
```

I also have a `public class MorrisBoard` with the following code:

```
public class MorrisBoard {
    public static final Ring RING = new Ring();

    private boolean checkMillBy(int ring, int x, int y) {
    switch(ring) {
    case MorrisBoard.RING.OUT:
        //...
    case MorrisBoard.RING.MID: //etc.
        //...   
    }
    return false;
}
```

`MorrisBoard.RING.OUT` references a variable which is immutable for the lifetime of the program. All values are final.

However, I still get the following error: `case expressions must be constant expressions`. I'm confused by this - `MorrisBoard.RING.OUT` is a constant expression.

What is going on here?

Comment: It must be a _compile time constant_, and `RING` isn't, it's assigned at runtime.

Comment: FYI: Consider using an `enum` instead of a bunch of `final static`...

Comment: There is no need to create an instance of a class which doesn't have any instance members i.e. only static members

Comment: ofcourse the expressions are not constant and cannot have objects in the case statements expressions

Comment: I have something equally idiotic going on. I import a static final constant that is an Integer from a Constants class. Then in a loop try and compare a loop index to the imported constant within the case of a switch. Also getting this bizarre message.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace

```
 case MorrisBoard.RING.OUT:
```

with

```
 case Ring.OUT:
```

So this will really be a constant as in "determined at compilation".

The specification [precises](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) that a "SwitchLabel" must be

- `case` followed by a constant expression
- `case` followed by the name of an enum value
- or `default`

What is considered a valid constant expression is [described here in the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). It's fairly limited.

Comment: Do you thing this will work when final class Ring is not static?

Comment: In this particular case, it is, so this is an appropriate answer (thank you!). However, I would be curious to know how that would be handled.

Comment: @Hurda If you can't refer to your externally defined constant simply with `TypeName.Identifier`, then it's not valid.

Answer (score 9):

Simple solution for this problem is :
Click on the **switch** and then press **CTL+1,** It will change your switch to if-else block statement, and will resolve your problem

Comment: BTW: This works for Spring Tool Suite - based on Eclipse IDE. Not sure if this works for IntelliJ or Netbeans the same way.