# Java how to use global variables in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have three integer global variables:

```
   public static int a = 1;
   public static int b = 2;
   public static int c = 3;
```

I want to do:

```
int code = dis.readInt();
switch(code)
{
    case a: 
    ......
    break;
    case b:
    ......
    break;
    case c:
    ......
    break;
}
```

But it is not working, can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: `But it is not working` Describe that. What do you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis "Case expression must be constant expression"

Comment: And what is a `constant expression`?

Comment: One that does not change. In this case: `public static final int x = 0;`

Comment: use final with global variables like `public final static int a = 1;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308129/case-expressions-must-be-constant-expressions-for-static-final-int

Comment: If you every see a static field which is not final, be afraid, be very afraid. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Java `switch` statement can accept "`Constant Expressions`" and "`Enum Constant Names`", as noted in section [14.11 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11).

If you can provide a bit more context, a better solution to the problem may be available; otherwise, this is as close as you get in Java:

```
public class Constant
{
    public static final int a=1;
    public static final int b=2;
    public static final int c=3;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if(0 == args.length)
        {
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        String string=args[0];
        int value=Integer.parseInt(string);

        switch(value)
        {
            case a:
                System.out.println("It's an 'a'");
                break;
            case b:
                System.out.println("It's an 'b'");
                break;
            case c:
                System.out.println("It's an 'c'");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println(String.format("It's a mystery '%s'",value));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have 1 character I wouldn't recommend using String, instead use char.

```
char string=args[0];
```

and then follow the answer Jan neilsen gave.